# Error while importing the packages

Tags: android, import, package

I am trying to understand the Tabs + ViewPager concepts in Android where I found this code while googling, http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/. I was just trying to copy paste and I found that:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

These 3 packages are unable to find their way i.e they are marked as an Error in my Eclipse and I am not very sure what to do with these packages.

Anybody help me in getting that right and please let me know why these packages are used for?

Comment: what is your application version? this package available in from 11 and above level

Comment: @Pratik I am using API level 8 and my application version is 2.2

Comment: check in android developer for filter to check the version. and you need to change it api level for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What API level you given to your Project...cause Fragment is available since Android 3.0..and for lower level api to use it,you will have to use jar file [From Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android/android-support-4.0.jar.zip)

Comment: the link appears to be broken and I am using API level 8

Comment: First two import statements are ok and the problem still persists with the 3rd import statement @Frankenstein

Comment: after adding that jar file to your project or after setting project version to 3.0?

Comment: after adding that jar file.Do I need to change the version to 3.0?No right?

Answer (score 7):

see here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#SettingUp

it basically says:

1. In your Android project, create a directory named libs at the root of your project (next to src/, res/, etc.)
2. Locate the JAR file for the library you want to use and copy it into the libs/ directory. For example, the library that supports API level 4 and up is located at /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar.
3. Add the JAR to your project build path: In Eclipse, right-click the JAR file in the Package Explorer, select "Build Path > Add to Build Path".
   (This step seems not to be necessary when using linux command line tools.)

NOTE: make sure you visit the link above for some important additional information

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the jar file from the sdk path. Found here

> (Your android sdk path$>
>   android-sdk-windows\extras\android\compatibility\v4

and add **android-support-v4** to your build path.
This is needed for using fragments.

Comment: Thats working great but still I am getting an error at the line import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

Comment: I tried to import the project it worked fine for me after adding the compatibility v4 sdk. It dint give any problem. See if you have the updated sdk especially the compatibility part in your android SDK manager. Btw cool concepts from that link.. I'm going through.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add appropriate Android support library to your project by doing the following:- **Right click on project >> Android Tools >> Add support library**

[image: Add support library]